# How to match numbers in a column from one dataframe to a column of coarser grained values in another dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr

So my problem is specifically with dates, where I have a dataframe with coarse date/time stamps (every 30 seconds), which has a unique identifier for each timestamp too, and then I have a longer dataframe with time samples every 0.5 seconds, and I want to add a column to the longer dataframe that says which identifier in the first dataframe each timestamp matches to.

Ignoring dates altogether, this could be as simple as this:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:3, value = seq(0,6,3))
b <- c(0.1,1.2,2.4,3.1,4.2,5.3,6.4)
```

and wanting an output

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you need `findInterval(b, a$value)` ?

Comment: Hi That sounds like exactly it! thank you!

Comment: One follow up: 

If I instead have 2 columns of values. Say instead I Have value1 = c(0,3,6) and value2 = c(1,4,7) and want the output c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,3), could I use findInterval somehow too? Or would some function within dplyr be what I need? 

Thanks and please post your response as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `findInterval`

```
findInterval(b, a$value)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

Or `cut`

```
cut(b, c(a$value, Inf), labels = FALSE)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

Comment: so marked as answer as this is exactly what I asked for, but with some further digging I might need to work this a slightly different way which I put a followup of. Maybe you can also answer this easily


If I instead have 2 columns of values. Say instead I Have value1 = c(0,3,6) and value2 = c(1,4,7) and want the output c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,3), could I use findInterval somehow too? Or would some function within dplyr be what I need?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is `value1` and `value2`? Is it in a dataframe or they are separate vectors?

Comment: I updated the original post with the follow-up made much clearer I hope

Comment: Bear in mind these 'regions' that are between value 1 and 2 will always be unique. 

So if on row 1, value1==0 and value2==1, there will never be another row with value1<=1

Comment: Probably, this should have been a new question but you can do : `sapply(b, function(x) a$id[which(x > a$value1 & x < a$value2)[1]])`

Comment: Hey sorry, yes I only realised after that these questions, whilst answering very similar problems in the context of my research, are quite distinct. I'm happy to post again as a question so both you can get the credit for answering 2 Qs and so other people can find the question more easily in the future:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459086/binning-a-vector-of-numbers-into-a-set-of-discrete-and-distinct-non-overlapping

Thanks again for all your help!