# Binning a vector of numbers into a set of discrete and distinct (non-overlapping) bins, with gaps, in R

Tags: r, dplyr

So my question is about dates but it can be most easily summarised by the problem below

```
a <- data.frame(id = c(123,456,789), value1 = c(0,3,6), value2 = c(1,4,7))
b <- c(0.1,1.2,2.4,3.1,4.2,5.3,6.4)
```

I want to find for which `id` in `a` does each value of b lie in between `value1` and `value2`, to give an output

```
123 NA NA 456 NA NA 789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sapply` :

```
sapply(b, function(x) a$id[which(x > a$value1 & x < a$value2)[1]])
#[1] 123  NA  NA 456  NA  NA 789
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[data.table(value = b), on = .(value1 < value, value2 > value)]$id
#[1] 123  NA  NA 456  NA  NA 789
```